# Automated Tests for System Configuration

Tags: configuration, testing

In software development, i like to do tests. 
But are there any useful frameworks for automated tests for system configurations?

I think like you may be able to test a Backup-MX configuration:
- whitebox test: domain should be in relay domains, domain may not be in mydestination
- blackbox test: e-mail to backup-domain should be forwarded, e-mail to backup domain may not be rejected, e-mail to backup-domain may not be delivered locally.

Is there any framework for doing such tests? Of course i could grab any programming language and write unit-tests with a lot of system-calls, but there might be a helpful tool. Does anyone know such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

Just come across the Requirements framework from Microsoft that does this

You define a set of "requirements", basically short scripts to test a piece of configuration and another script to set it, and you can then run this against a machine and it will report on all the tests and remediate them

https://github.com/microsoft/requirements

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about tests as such, but you can use tools like Puppet (http://puppetlabs.com/) to enforce a given configuration over a group of machines.

Comment: not what i really want. I want to write a Feature-Test, which verifies the Feature is configured the right way. Best Tests would be composed from two parts: white-box, testing the configuration which should be used is used, black-box, testing the configured functionality is really working as the service-user would expect it.